# jQuery data attribute click event

Tags: jquery

I have made a quick fiddle to outline my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mYdxw/

I'm trying to click on a div, grab its data attribute and show its corresponding set of divs.

Can anyone spot why it isn't doing this currently?

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.categoryItems').click(function() {
        $('.itemLinks').hide();
        var target_category = $(this).attr('data-target_category');
        $('.itemLinks [data-category=' + target_category + ']').show();
    });
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="categories">
    <div data-target_category="html-site-templates" class="categoryItems">HTML Site Templates</div>
    <div data-target_category="jquery-plugins" class="categoryItems">jQuery Plugins</div>
    <div data-target_category="tumblr-themes" class="categoryItems">Tumblr Themes</div>
    <div data-target_category="wordpress-themes" class="categoryItems">WordPress Themes</div>    
</div>

<div id="content">
    <a class="itemLinks" data-category="tumblr-themes" href="/tumblr-themes/mini-tumblr-theme/">Mini Tumblr Theme</a>
    <a class="itemLinks" data-category="jquery-plugins" href="/jquery-plugins/randomr-jquery-plugin/">Randomr jQuery Plugin</a>
    <a class="itemLinks" data-category="wordpress-themes" href="/wordpress-themes/redux-wp-theme/">Redux WP Theme</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Always include the relevant code/markup *in the question itself*. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This...

```
$('.itemLinks [data-category=' + target_category + ']').show();
```

should be this...

```
$('.itemLinks[data-category="' + target_category + '"]').show();
```

The space is interpreted as a *descendant selector*, but the `data-category` is directly on the `itemLinks` element, not on a descendant.

I also added quotes around the value of the attribute selector. The API requires it.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mYdxw/11/

Answer (score 15):

Just to improve on the code, jQuery provides .data() to retrieve the value of the dataset so instead of using attr() use data()

```
 var target_category = $(this).data('target_category');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mYdxw/28/

Comment: The above code is HTML 5 compliant and jQuery effort towards making life easier for developers.http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/jquery-data-method/

Comment: @benhowdle89: All it does is import the data attribute into jQuery's `.data()` system. If all you're going to do is read the data, it really doesn't make a difference. Since you're already using `data-` attributes, you're already HTML5 compliant. jQuery doesn't actually use the HTML5 `dataset` property to read the data. But after enough browsers support it, you'll be able to do `this.dataset.target_category` to retrieve the data.

Comment: Well right but its always nice to have toolset to play around, its my personal opinion.

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying that unless you actually have a use for it in jQuery's data cache, it doesn't make too much difference. Ultimately the best way to access it will be with the `dataset` property, but that won't be until there's enough support.